# Can we recover shape changes from spectrum changes?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

This is a question related to the ["hearing the shape of a drum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum) problem. There are well-known examples of different shapes (non-isometric manifolds) which yield the same eigenvalue spectrum. However, has the following related problem been studied?

Supposing a perturbation in the shape of a vibrating drum (let's say, to be more precise, a small change in its metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow (I+f)g_{\mu\nu}$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function), can we recover the function $f$ from studying the small change in its spectrum?

Any reference would be appreciated.